# How can I add custom fields in a custom post type?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I'm creating a custom post type for my wordpress site. But I want to remove the editor an put a field for uploading files. How do I do that?

Comment: Show some specific problem's code or try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the plugin "Advance Custom Fields" which is such a time-saver, awesome plugin, one of few plugins I use for all my WP-projects. It's easy and slick.

If you really don't want to use a plugin you can read the documentation here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

It has examples on how to add a metabox with custom fields to your post type.

```
add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $post_type, $context, $priority, $callback_args );
```

Where $post_type is the slug-name of your post-type.

Edit:
To remove elements like the WSIWYG-editor, you need to specify this when creating the post-type. The "supports" array takes in strings with what you want the post-type to be able to handle.

Answer (score 0):

There is a direct function to achieve this if you are not adding the 'support' via the register_post_type array.

```
 <?php
 add_action('init', 'my_custom_init');

 function my_custom_init() {
      add_post_type_support( 'books', 'custom-fields' );
 }
 ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support